# React native variable state is being preserved only on some screens

Tags: react-native, navigation, screen, reset

I'm just starting with React Native. I have 2 screens (Favorites and Recipes) both with just one const `valor` and basically the exact same code except for the second button in order to navigate between screens.

The problem:

If I use the first button to increment the value of `valor` in the Recipes screen, navigate to Favorites and back to Recipes everything is ok and the value remains the last one I set. But if I navigate to Favorites, change the value there, go to Recipes and back to Favorites the value resets back to 1 on the Favorites screen. Why is this?

```
const RecipesScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const [ valor, setValor ] = useState(1);

    return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        
        <Text style={{top: 100}}>variable is recipes is now { valor }</Text>
        
        <View style={{marginTop: 140}} >
            <Button onPress={ () => { setValor(valor+1); }} title="INCREMENT"></Button>
            <Button onPress={ () => { navigation.navigate("Favorites"); }} title="Go to favorites"></Button>
        </View>

    </View>
    );
}
```

```
const FavoritesScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    const [ valor, setValor ] = useState(1);

    return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        
        <Text style={{top: 100}}>variable is favorites is now { valor }</Text>
        
        <View style={{marginTop: 140}} >
            <Button onPress={ () => { setValor(valor+1); }} title="INCREMENT"></Button>
            <Button onPress={ () => { navigation.navigate("Recipes"); }} title="Go to recipes"></Button>
        </View>

    </View>
    );
}
```

```
import RecipesScreen from './RecipesScreen.js';
import FavoritesScreen from './FavoritesScreen.js';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{animationEnabled: false, headerShown: false }} >
        <Stack.Screen name="Recipes" component={RecipesScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoritesScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **navigation in react work as a stack** last in first out.

The **state in your component persists until it is unmount** by react.

In your first example Recipe is the root of your stack, then you add Favorites in your stack and remove it. During this operation **Recipe was still mounted in your navigation so the state is preserved**.

In the second example Favorites is the last component in your navigation. **When you go back to Recipes the component Favorites is unmount and the state is lost**. When you go back to Favorites again the component is mounted with the default state value.

You can search in this [document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle) for more information.

Comment: Oh ok I understand @docmurloc, thank you. So is this navigation the wrong approach for what I want to do? What should I do to be able to navigate between screens at will and not have them reset variable states?

Comment: If you want to preserve your state, you have to save it outside of your component with [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [react redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)